# What are you reading at the moment?

Tags: word-request

No, not what books are you enjoying, but what specifically is *this* page, that you're reading *right now*.

On other sites such as forums etc, we may be involved in a "thread".  What single word or short phrase would best describe the interactions we have on Stack Exchange.

For more context, I was posting a comment on another site's Meta, and wanted to say:

> As mentioned elsewhere on this ...

- "thread" doesn't work, because we're not a forum
- "Q&A" just doesn't seem right

Comment: Normally this would probably go on ELU, but I suppose it's not really off-topic here exactly either.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I think it's a good choice for ELL. Learning English is a lifetime job, even for us natives. :)

Comment: I would like to point out that "at this very moment" means, literally, "right now".

Comment: @MrLister I completely agree.  The new title also didn't match the intention of my first sentence "no, not what books...", so have rolled back the edit.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I forgot about the existence of ELU, and when I saw the "word-request" tag here, figured that it must be acceptable here too?  Perhaps someone with 3K rep could confirm whether there's a close->migrate path to ELU from ELL for questions that warrant it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on English Language & Usage.

Answer (score 6):

If I'm talking with someone in person, especially someone not familiar with StackExchange, I'll call this **a page**.

On StackExchange, I'll usually call it **a question**. "A question" can refer to the whole page, including the answers and comments, especially when written on a different page. On the page, **the question** usually refers only to the question part of the page, excluding the answers and comments.

Comment: +1 Exactly my thought! In my opinion, "question" is the right word, not only because the reason mentioned above, but the URL convention emphasizes this. SE assigns a unique ID to each question. For example, the URL of this page at the moment is `http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59293/what-are-you-reading-right-now-at-this-very-moment`; we can also access the same question via its ID: `http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59293`, or its shorthand: `http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/59293`.